# angular2 login page for a web client to a back-end REST service

Tags: rest, security, authentication, angular

I am writing an Angular2 client web application client as a front end for a REST services providing access to some resources.

The REST service is protected with basic HTTP auth, and allows unauthenticated access for some of its endpoints (for instance `GET /freeresource`), while requires user/password authentication for other endpoints (say `GET /protectedresource`, or `POST /freeresource`, etc.).

For my Angular2 client, I would like to implement a loging page allowing access to the web application with the same ":" accepted by REST service. For this I'm following this tutorial : https://medium.com/@blacksonic86/angular-2-authentication-revisited-611bf7373bf9#.myifbz656

The problem is that the above tutorial assumes that the backend REST service has an explicit `/login` endpoint returning an authentication token to which you post your credentials, while my REST service does not have such an endpoint, but just returns an authorization error when passed missing or wrong credentials for endpoints that require them. I didn't find any alternative article or tutorial for a situation like this.

What is the correct way of proceeding in such a case? I could "simulate" the `/login` endpoint by accessing for instance a protected resource with username and password read from the app login page and trying to access a protected resource `GET /protectedresource`, considering as a failed login if this call returns an `unauthorized` error, but clearly this is not a satisfying solution (what today is a protected resource could become freely accessible tomorrow, for instance), so what is a "clean" way to implement the web app login in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to simulate the /login endpoint. You just need to know on the client accessing which resource requires authentication. You can implement the same "CanActivate" method from the tutorial, and write your service call to pass credentials (or use the local storage if the user is authenticated already) when you make the REST call. If your REST endpoints require authentication every time, get them from the user at the login page, store them in the local storage, then pass them to the endpoints that need authentication.

Comment: The only problem with this solution is that I wish I could give an immediate feedback to the user at the login page (login successful / unsuccessful) before actually having to request information about any specific resource (which is done in following screens in the UI). That's why I suggested in my answer to issue some "premature" GET request to some protected resources (ie. before my UI actually needs this) just to check whether the provided username/password are valid. Probably there is no real solution to my question without being able to change the back end REST service. Thanks anyhow.